# Creating a season column corresponding to month column

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm new to R, trying to figure out what I've done wrong here. I have a column with month names in them (January - December) and trying to fit a column with seasons corresponding to the month. This is my workings so far:

```
House$Season <- ifelse (House$month %in% c('May','June','July'), 
"SUMMER",
ifelse (House$month %in% c('August','September','October'), 
"AUTUMN",
ifelse (House$month %in% c('November','December','January'), 
"WINTER",
ifelse (House$month %in% c('February','March','April')), 
"SPRING"))))
```

I've tried many different things but this is what I'm currently on. I know I'm probably completely off, I'm beginner as I said so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add something like `NA` after `"SPRING",`. pay attention to the comma after `SPRING`.

Comment: You forgot the alternative... `ifelse(..., 'SPRING', NA)` or cut it at the previous statement and do `ifelse(..., 'WINTER', 'SPRING')`

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I've tried adding ,NA after 'SPRING', to no avail unfortunately. I'll look into cut, I'm not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure @Sotos' solution doesn't mean the function `cut`, but instead to stop/cut at the third `ifelse`, with "SPRING" as the final "no" value:

```
House$Season <- ifelse(House$month %in% c('May','June','July'), "SUMMER",
                    ifelse (House$month %in% c('August','September','October'), "AUTUMN",
                            ifelse (House$month %in% c('November','December','January'), 
                                    "WINTER", "SPRING")))
```

Each `ifelse` needs both a "yes" and a "no" value. Your last statement didn't have a "no."

Alternatively if you're worried about non-month entries in the month column, you can keep the final statement with NA as your "no". Your issue there appears to be that you have too many closing parentheses in `c('February','March','April'))`

```
House <- data.frame(month = c("January", "March", "June", "September", "Not a month"))

House$Season <- ifelse (House$month %in% c('May','June','July'), 
"SUMMER",
ifelse (House$month %in% c('August','September','October'), 
"AUTUMN",
ifelse (House$month %in% c('November','December','January'), 
"WINTER",
ifelse (House$month %in% c('February','March','April'), 
"SPRING", NA))))
```

Comment: Aaaaah, I understand! It works! Thank you all very much for your responses, that's been wrecking my head for days! Much appreciated!